# Nested attributes validation on updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two model `Product` and `ProductBoxing`, product has many product_boxings.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many   :product_boxings
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_boxings 
   validates :name, presence: { presence: true, message: 'please give a name' }, on: :update
end
```

**product_boxing.rb**

```
class ProductBoxing < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   validates :quantity, presence: { presence: true, message: 'please fill in quantity' }, on: :update 
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@product, html: {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form", multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name%>
  <%= f.fields_for :product_boxings do |g| %>        
      <%= g.text_field :quantity %>     
  <% end %>     
<% end %>
```

For some reasons, I create both `product` and `product_boxing` without validation first. After that, I want to validate both on updating. The validation works for `Product`, but not for `ProductBoxing`.

Are there any problem in my code? or it is a rails issue?

BTW,  I remove validation option  `on: :update` and validate both on creating, the validations work for both.

### update

At first, user will ran the follow code

```
 def new
   product = Product.new
   p_b= product.product_boxings.build() 
   product.save!    
   redirect_to edit_product_path(product)
 end
```

then

```
 def edit
 end
```

and post form

```
 def update
   @product.update(product_params)

   unless @product.errors.any?  
     redirect_to products_url      
   else  
     render 'edit'
   end   
 end
```

### other info

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, product_boxings_attributes:[:id, :quantity] )
end
```

Comment: Can you post the params log generated? And can you confirm that `product_boxing` is updating normally?

Comment: Can you post the strong_params method in the question?

Comment: In the question please..

Comment: I found a new situation, if quantity has been filled, the validations of quantity works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure the validation of your associated model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many   :product_boxings
   validates_associated :product_boxings
   #  ...
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

**TEST THE MODELS WITH THE CONSOLE**

```
> p = Product.new
> p.valid?
> p.errors
> p.product_boxings.each { |pb| pb.valid?; pb.errors }
```

If you want to see this product_boxings messages in the error list, you should create a custom validation.

```
validate :associated_product_boxings

def associated_product_boxings
  product_boxings.each do |product_boxing|
     errors.add (...) unless product_boxing.valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it works but it shows the default error message "is invalid" of **validates_associated :product_boxings**,  not the message generated by  **validates :quantity, presence: { presence: true, message: 'please fill in quantity' }, on: :update**

Comment: You can see the complete list of errors in the console. I have updated my answer. If the presence validation is in the list, it is working fine. Think that it validates in secuencial order.